How to create multiple Javascript DataTransfer object with loop & access them
I want to create multiple DataTransfer objects in a for loop & then use them. But it is not working.
var cars = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];

for(let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    var cars[i] = new DataTransfer();
}

This is showing: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['
Then I would like to use them according to the id or class like:
<span id="testing" value="test1"></span>


var f = new File([""], "filename.txt", {type: "text/plain"})
$("#testing").attr('value').items.add(f);

With above I get this error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
I don't know what I am missing. Thanks in advance!

Remove var in var cars[i]

What is $? Is it jQuery? Please add the tag... Why do you expect an items property in what attr() returns?

This is showing: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['
The issue is your statement in your for loop
var cars = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];

for(let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    // You are trying to declare a variable name here, and brackets are not valid characters in variable names
    var cars[i] = new DataTransfer();
}

if you're just trying to set the value at each index of your array, you can just set them without declaring a variable:
var cars = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];

for(let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    cars[i] = new DataTransfer();
}

With above I get this error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
This is because the value of your span is a string "test1" which does not have a method/property called items. I can only guess you're trying to use your DataTransfer object there, so you would need to access it in a different way. Perhaps in your javascript you could set up an object with keys to access your objects:
var cars = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];
var dataTransfers = {};

for(let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    // dataTrasnfers.test1 = new DataTransfer() when i = 1
    dataTransfers[cars[i]] = new DataTransfer();
}

From there, dataTransfers.test1, dataTransfers.test2, dataTransfers.test3, dataTransfers.test4 are all valid. You can continue grabbing those names from your span values.

Thanks @eric, That solved my half problem.  "dataTransfers.test1" is working for me. What if I get 'test1' from a html element's id or class.  Then as you mentioned, "test1" is string, how would  I use this like "dataTransfers.$("#testing").attr('id')"?

So once you have 'test1' from your html element's id/class, you would directly access the dataTransfers object you made.
var myId = $("#testing").attr('id'); // test1 var dataTransfer = dataTransfers[myId]; if(dataTransfer) // Your data transfer was found, do whatever you need with it else // The id you are searching for is not in the object
Let me know if that helps @NitinS!

See my updated comment, I accidentally posted it before I had it all written out!

Great!. Solved. Thanks very much!
